# How to post messages on my wall using restfb

Tags: restfb

How to post messages on my wall using restfb ?

I am using this code

```
    PostData(String accessToken) {
      facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);
 }
     void runMessage() {
            String messageId = publishMessage();
     }
 String publishMessage() {
    System.out.println("* Feed publishing *"); 
    FacebookType publishMessageResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/feed", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", "RestFB test"),Parameter.with("link", "http://www.google.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with me. Did you add publish_stream permission to you permissions?

More information see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me :

```
static final String MY_ACCESS_TOKEN;

static{MY_ACCESS_TOKEN  = 

/*

login to facebook then copy your access token from "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=605545976%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname" and paste it here

*/}

//-------

FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(MY_ACCESS_TOKEN);

void post(String message){
facebookClient.publish("me/feed",FacebookType.class,Parameter.with("message",message));
}
```

Comment: i'm new to restFB my self, so i see no big difference between your code and mine ... maybe if you put your link as String in your message will work the same way ... i dont know !!!

but what i'm sure of is that this code works fine

and make sure your token didnt get expired as well